# What is the Dojo equivalent of jQuery's innerHeight()?

Tags: dojo

In jQuery, we can use innerHeight to get the height of one element (including padding but not border.).

```
$("selector").innerHeight();
```

How can I get the same value by dojo?

What my solution is using

```
dojo.contentBox() //get the height of content box
dojo.style(node, "borderTopWidth") //get width of border-top
dojo.style(node, "borderBottomWidth"). //get width of border-left
```

Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is an easier way to do it.

You basically have three choices:

```
dojo.contentBox(node) // excludes border, padding and margin
dojo.position(node)   // includes border and padding; excludes margin
dojo.marginBox(node)  // includes border, padding and margin
```

So, you need to do what you suggested. Use `dojo.contentBox()`, then separately calculate the top and bottom border widths.

Alternatively you might want to place a `<div>` inside a `<div>`, so that you can set the border on the outer div and keep the padding on the inner div. You would then be able to get the required height from calling `dojo.position()` for the inner div.

```
<div id="outer" style="border: solid #000 1px;">
  <div id="inner" style="height: 20px; padding: 2px;">.</div>
</div>
<script>
  alert(dojo.position("inner").h) // 24
</script>
```

Comment: well, the position can get the real data as your solution, but I can't change the structure of the html. so the inside div doesn't exist for me and all the attributes are defined for the ourside div("#outer"), include padding border and blablabla.